# Point sampling raster with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I am developing a PostGIS query to sample rasters using a point table to detect land cover change. I have read the documentation on [ST_value](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_ST_Value.html) and I am able to get the raster value of a single point using the following query:

```sql
SELECT  rid, ST_Value(rast, 1, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(484375.820,4742079.979), 32617)) as b1
FROM imagery.l8_2015_09_12 
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(484375.820,4742079.979), 32617)::geometry, 1);
```

However, when sampling using a table of points, I cannot get ST_Value to work. When running the following query in the SQL window of QGIS:

```sql
-- sample a raster from a table of points 
SELECT ST_Value(r.rast, 3, p.geom) As band3
FROM analysis_results.sample_points AS p, imagery.l8_2015_09_12 AS r
WHERE ST_Intersects(r.rast,p.geom);
```

I get the following error:

`Attempting to get the value of a pixel with a non-point geometry`

The table has a multipoint geometry data type, so why is ST_value not playing nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ST_Value is strict about wanting a Point rather than a MultiPoint; one way to bypass this is to use [ST_Dump](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html).  Taking your first query and converting the Point to a MultiPoint:

```sql
SELECT 
    rid,
    ST_Value(rast, 1, 
        (ST_Dump(
            ST_Multi(
                ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(484375.820, 4742079.979), 32617)
            )
        )).geom
    ) AS b1 
FROM imagery.l8_2015_09_12 
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(484375.820, 4742079.979), 32617)::geometry, 1);
```

Comment: So I need to convert the mulltipoint to point for the second query to work?

Comment: Yep, ST_Value(r.rast, 3, (ST_Dump(p.geom)).geom).

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your help! I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works to sample a raster using a table of points.

```
SELECT rid, ST_Value(r.rast, 3, (ST_Dump(p.geom)).geom) As band3
FROM analysis_results.sample_points AS p, imagery.l8_2015_09_12 AS r
WHERE ST_Intersects(r.rast, ST_SetSRID(p.geom, 32617)::geometry, 1);
```